# Dropbox saver button warning icon

Tags: php, html, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to add a Dropbox Saver button to my website so my users have the option to save files to their dropbox account instead of downloading them. I've got the button setup correctly but the button throws a warning when I click on it. The error isn't outputted to the browser console either so I literally have no idea what's wrong.

As you can see from the image below, the standard `advice.png` file supplied by DropBox works perfectly with the button, but any file from my domain just seems to fail.

[image]

I've tried reading through the [Saver's documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/saver) a few times, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I've also tried testing this with more than one file on my server as I said above.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
echo '
<div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/1/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="jea46s19s3r8dou"></script> 
    <a href="'.base_url()."uploads/".$notesDetails['filename'].'" class="dropbox-saver"></a>
    <a href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/deroi5nwm6u7gdf/advice.png" class="dropbox-saver"></a>
    <a href="https://notedu.mp/uploads/small/eded5ff825cf367e36ab2f57fcccb218.jpg" class="dropbox-saver"></a>
</div>';
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by smarx, the problem isn't with my code, but DropBox's code. It's all a matter of the waiting game here until this problem is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a bug on our (Dropbox's) side, since other domains are working. We'll investigate.

Comment: Nice to see one of the Dropbox devs replying to this question :) It's worth pointing out that my domain is a .mp domain and I'm using SSL. Does this make any difference? Thanks

Comment: The issue is understood. We see it on a small number of domains, and we're investigating possible fixes.